# How to Send an email when user made a booking using Woocommerce Booking

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, woocommerce-bookings

I want to notify **both** **user and admin** through an email when user made a booking in **[WooCommerce Bookings](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/)**. 
Now it is sending mail only to admin to confirm booking.

Can anyone give me right direction, as how to achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: I'll suggest you to contact Plugin Author for this, as it is a paid plugin so they will provide you the good support. Or else you can check this [Email Notifications](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/the-customer-booking-process/#section-3).

Answer (score 0):

It's a piece of cake.

```
function my_awesome_shipping_notification($order_id, $checkout = null) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    if ($order->status === 'on-hold') {

        // Create a mailer
        $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();

        $message_body = __('Order placed: Waiting for confirmation.', 'text_domain');

        $message = $mailer->wrap_message(
                // Message head and message body.
                sprintf(__('Order %s ready for shipping', 'text_domain'), $order->get_order_number()), $message_body);

        // Client email, email subject and message.
        $result = $mailer->send($order->billing_email, sprintf(__('Order %s received', 'text_domain'), $order->get_order_number()), $message);

        //error_log( $result );
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'my_awesome_shipping_notification');
```

Hope this helps.

**Reference:** [https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bookings-action-and-filter-reference/][1]

Comment: i want put only  "wait for confirmation " how can i add this

Comment: Can you explain more about "wait for confirmation" ? What does that means, Do you need to display a message or send an email ?

Comment: i want send an email and mail content is "wait for confirmation"

Comment: Okay, It's pretty much clear in aforementioned answer, You can get order details by order id. It will contains user_id of customer and you can write send email code inside the method.

Comment: can you tell me all code in function i am new to wordpress

Comment: Yes, give it a try, i didn't tested it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125083/discussion-between-kapil-yadav-and-vinit).

Comment: Updated code is working, tested. If you are using localhost and linux then install sendmail.

Comment: its not working in my theme i am using listify wordpres theme

Answer (score 0):

read the plugin documentation!

WooCommerce Bookings has five email alerts that are handled for you automatically. You can edit all emails sent to customers at: WooCommerce > Settings > Emails. They are:

1. New Booking: Emails are sent to the admin when a new booking is created.
2. Booking Confirmed: Emails are sent when a booking is confirmed.
3. Booking Reminder: Emails are sent to the customer one day prior to their booking to remind them of an upcoming booking.
4. Booking Notification: Notification emails are sent manually from WooCommerce > Bookings > Send Notification.
5. Booking Cancelled: Emails are sent when a booking is cancelled.

[source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/the-customer-booking-process/)